# Font Awesome and drop down list

Tags: html, css, fonts, html-select, font-awesome

I have a problem with Font Awesome and IE9/IE10.
I have a select list with a few icons of Font Awesome inside that the user can pick.
I made it this way :

```
<select name="pic" id="pic"> 
    <option value="icon-adjust">&#xf042;</option>
    <option value="icon-asterisk">&#xf069;</option>
    <option value="icon-ban-circle">&#xf05e;</option>
    <option value="icon-bar-chart">&#xf080;</option>
    <option value="icon-barcode">&#xf02a;</option>
    <option value="icon-beaker">&#xf0c3;</option>
    <option value="icon-beer">&#xf0fc;</option>
</select>
```

The icons are displayed properly in FF, Chrome and Opera but it doesn't work with IE. Another thing is that in IE, the dropdown list shows blank options but when you pick one, the selected icon appears.

Can someone can give me a hand or just explain to me what I am doing wrong? It would be much appreciated! Thank you very much!

Comment: It doesn't work at Chrome.

Comment: Really strange... It works for me. Is there another way to display the icons of Font Awesome in a drop down list ?

Comment: Ok, works on Chrome, but IE simply doesn't support such font. You can't do anything about it.

Comment: Hum... Such a sad thing.

Comment: which IE version are you using?

Comment: does not work in chrome 30.0.1599.69 m on win7

Comment: I did something with this plugin : http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/ It is not really what I wanted but, now it's working.